# Modify readonly members in a class

Tags: c#, monogame

I am learning Monogame these days and there is a class called "Texture2D" that has two readonly members Width and Height. They take values from actual graphic used. Is there any way that I can change their values so that the width and height of the texture changes (either by deriving from it or some other way)? And if I derive from it, then how will I obtain its object from Content.Load() method?

Comment: When you change the size of the texture, what do you expect it to do? Stretch? That should probably be done when the texture is put on a surface.

Comment: If a property is `readonly` it is intented to be readonly. you have to create new instance of `Texture2D` and pass new width and height in constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change the width/height of the source texture.

Use the [`SpriteBatch.Draw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433986.aspx) method with the Destination Rectangle.

```
void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();

    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), Color.White);

    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

Take a look at the [other overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch.Draw.aspx) for Scale and Rotation.